# SQL create linked fuzzy records

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have a set of records:

```
ID  DESCRIPTION     VALUE
1    HORSE JOCKEY     200      
2    HORSE JOCK       300
3    SOCKS            50
4    HORSE JOCKE      200
```

Which I have already run a string distance function over to include with only pairs of high probability matches

```
ID1  DESCRIPTION1    VALUE1  ID2  DESCRIPTION2     VALUE2  STRING_DISTANCE
 1    HORSE JOCKEY     200    2    HORSE JOCK        300        95
 1    HORSE JOCKEY     200    4    HORSE JOCKE       200        97
 2    HORSE JOCK       300    4    HORSE JOCKE       200        98
```

How do I then link these records to create one unique ID (say 10 for Horse Jockey) for assuming all the above are supposed to be HORSE JOCKEY but have typos? Similair to below:

```
ID1  DESCRIPTION1    VALUE1  ID2  DESCRIPTION2     VALUE2  STRING_DISTANCE UNIQUE_ID   
 1    HORSE JOCKEY     200    2    HORSE JOCK        300        95             10
 1    HORSE JOCKEY     200    4    HORSE JOCKE       200        97             10
 2    HORSE JOCK       300    4    HORSE JOCKE       200        98             10
```

Ultimately looking for

```
ID  DESCRIPTION     VALUE   UNIQUE_ID
1    HORSE JOCKEY     200      10
2    HORSE JOCK       300      10
3    SOCKS            50       11
4    HORSE JOCKE      200      10
```

Comment: Based on what though? What if you also have `Norse Jack` with a string_distance of `92`(guessing) to `Horse Jock`. Does that get grouped with `Horse Jockey`?  I'm thinking that a recursive cte would do the trick here.

Comment: That's parameter that can be defined. Let's say for now I assume all pairs over 90 are matched.

Comment: The problem is, the distance between `HORSE JOCKEY` and `HORSE JOCK`  is same as the distance between `HORSE JOCK` and `HORSE JOCKEY` (which you don't show). So the problem is you need a rule to explain why the UID should identify  `HORSE JOCKEY` rather than any other record.

Comment: At this point I've already removed cross duplicates like this so that Horse Jockey only scores against Horse Jock once and not in reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique ID returned will be the ID of the item in the group that has the longest string length for the description (since the other strings appear to be sub-strings of that string) and if there are multiple longest length descriptions then the minimum of those IDs is used:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63a4d/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( ID, DESCRIPTION, VALUE ) AS
SELECT 1, 'HORSE JOCK', 300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'HORSE JOCKEY', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'SOCKS', 50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'HORSE JOCKE', 200 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id,
       description,
       value,
       MIN( CONNECT_BY_ROOT( id ) )
         KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY LENGTH( CONNECT_BY_ROOT( description ) ) )
         AS unique_id
FROM   your_table t
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER ( PRIOR description,  description ) >= 0.95
GROUP BY
       id,
       description,
       value
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/63a4d/1/0)**:

```
| ID |  DESCRIPTION | VALUE | UNIQUE_ID |
|----|--------------|-------|-----------|
|  1 |   HORSE JOCK |   300 |         2 |
|  2 | HORSE JOCKEY |   200 |         2 |
|  3 |        SOCKS |    50 |         3 |
|  4 |  HORSE JOCKE |   200 |         2 |
```

Comment: Thanks so much works great. One thing though if possible - If I have a large number of records and want to match only those that satisfy a specific condition such as same 'Racetrack Shop'. How can I put a filter in the above to only match those records?

Comment: Very good solution. However, *"unique ID returned will be the ID of the item in the group that has the longest string length for the description"*  is an inferred rule. If the table contained a value `HORSE JOCKEYZ` then that would be the target UID. Which is why I asked @Rtab where their rules for determining the UID were.

Comment: `UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER` : Never knew anything like this could have possibly existed.

Comment: @APC you could just use `MIN( CONNECT_BY_ROOT( id ) )` without the `KEEP` clause and it will get the lowest ID in the group - I included the `KEEP` clause as an example of how to perform a slightly more complicated piece of logic to get the "best" id from the group.

Comment: @Rtab If you want to just have those that are similar to `'Racetrack Shop'` then include `STARTS WITH description = 'Racetrack Shop'` between the `FROM` clause and the `CONNECT BY` clause. (Or if you don't know if there is an exact match then something like `STARTS WITH UTL_MATCH.JARO_WINKLER( description, 'Racetrack Shop' ) > 0.95`.

Comment: @KaushikNayak There are a few functions in the [`UTL_MATCH` package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_match.htm#ARPLS71213) including `EDIT_DISTANCE` and `JARO_WINKLER` for calculating the similarity between strings.

Comment: @MTO Thanks. I tried what you suggested previously. However I don't want just specificy 'Racetrack Shop'. It could be any shop as such so. I don't want to specify one but rather only match the ones that have the same 'Shop' type. Would the only way be to loop through using each individual 'shop name' or can I do it in one process?

Comment: @Rtab You could do `START WITH UPPER( description ) LIKE '%SHOP%'`

Comment: Thanks @MTO. I'm sorry I wasn't clear. Your response would totally solve my question otherwise. Its doesn't have to be an item with 'Shop' in the name. It can any sort of of parent inventory item  in the name. Would you think this is possible? Basically trying to put a where clause before the 'connect by nocycle' to only match when a.certain_condition = b.certain_condition. A being item to be matched to B so as to not run the string distance package on all records unnecessarily.